# Return from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android

I noticed throughout the tests, that Fragment does not have onBackPressed, same in the Activitys.

My problem is this: I have an Activity and it takes to a Fragment, in that Fragment I have a back button on the toolbar (which is working correctly and coming back without presenting any errors) and has the back button of the devices.

Basically the flow looks like this: MainActivity - MessagesActivity - ConversationsFragment - Conversa Activity.

I need to do management between the ConversationsFragment and MessagesActivity screens.

How could I do this management, as I do in onBackPressed, the back button of the devices?

Comment: Why can't you handle this in onBackPressed() of the Activity that's holding the Fragment?

Comment: Doesnt have onBackPressed in Fragment

Comment: I know. But your Fragment is contained in an Activity.

Comment: Ohhh yeah, let me test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically use an interface of base class for this. So create a

BaseFragment

that every fragment extends that needs it. Inside the BaseFragment add:

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CHILD METHODS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * To handle backpress down in fragments
 * Called from Parent Activity through BaseFragment Reference and regular onBackPressed

 * @return true if handled down here to avoid letting parent handle it
 */
open fun onBackPressed(): Boolean {
    //override if you care about it in fragment
    return false
}
```

Now in your Fragment just override the onBackPress and return true if you handle it otherwise super.onBackpressed() is going to return false for you.

Example 
HomeFragment

```
 override fun onBackPressed(): Boolean{
        //if connect dialog is open and didn't handle the on back pressed then call parent onbackpressed
        if(mConnectDialog == null){
            return mConnectDialog!!.onBackPressed()
        }else{
            return super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

In that example, there may be a dialog open that i want to close on back press before the activity would close itself.

Next up in the Activity you have to handle it like:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(mSelectedFragment != null){
        if(!mSelectedFragment!!.onBackPressed()){
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

So as you can see the Activity onBackPress checks if there is a fragment that needs to handle it first. If the fragment returns False (not handled) then it goes to the next caller. In this case it is the super, but you can customize that for your needs.

This is done in Kotlin, but you can paste and convert to Java if you need to as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in kotlin:

```
    view.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    view.requestFocus()
    // TODO DETECT BACK PRESSED IN FRAGMENT
    view.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event!!.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //sendResultBack()
            closeActivity()
            return@OnKeyListener true
        }
        false
    })
```

in java :

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus();
view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i(tag, "keyCode: " + keyCode);
            if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.i(tag, "onKey Back listener is working!!!");
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load the fragment add a boolean `loaded = true`;

Then

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (loaded) {
    // remove the fragment
    loaded = false;
  }
  else {
    // start the previous activity
  }
}
```